# Properly Initialize Client Side Model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, entity-framework, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My issue is very simple. I am using ASP Web API, Entity Framework, Angular, and Kendo UI. I have 2 classes, FREQUENCY and FREQ_TYPE_. Class FREQUENCY has a navigation property to class FREQ_TYPE. I have a kendo ui grid that loads 10 class FREQUENCY models. Each class FREQUENCY model has it's FREQ_TYPE data loaded properly. My problem is that when I create a new row in my kendo ui grid and try to save the row to the server, I get an error saying the navigation property FREQ_TYPE needs to be initialized. This is expected of course since kendo doesn't know how to auto=initialize my nav properties.

What is the best practice for giving my angular JS client the knowledge it needs to create a new class FREQ_TYPE so I can properly initialize class FREQUENCY  and save it to the server? My models only exist as code-first entity models, so I can't just create a new model in my client side JS as it doesn't know about these models. Is there some framework that can generate local model classes from an EF database? Or do I just have to manually set all the json fields for my class FREQ_TYPE navigation property? Or is there an easier way for me to use Web API so that I can make a request to "figure out" what the model info is and create a client side JS model without needing to have a "local model"?

Here is the client side grid and datasource:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://localhost:29858/";

        var NIICDDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "api/NIICDFreq",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                update: {

                    url: function (data) {
                        console.log("DATA TEST");
                        console.log(data);
                        return crudServiceBaseUrl + "api/NIICDFreq/";
                    },

                  //  url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "api/VHFMasterLists",

                    dataType: "json",
                    data: function (data) {
                        console.log("returning data in update TEST");
                        console.log(data.models[0]);
                        return data.models[0];
                    },
                    type: "PUT",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                },
                destroy: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "api/NIICDFreq",
                    dataType: "json"
                },
                create: {
                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "api/NIICDFreq",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }, 


                parameterMap: function (model, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && model) {
                        return kendo.stringify(model);
                    } else {
                        return  kendo.stringify(model) ;
                    }
                }
            },
            batch: true,
            pageSize: 20,
            schema: {
                data: function (data) { //specify the array that contains the data
                    console.log("DATA RETURN TEST");
                    console.log(data);
                    return data || [];
                },
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { editable: false,
                            nullable: false,
                            type: "number"
                        },
                        Frequency: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        $("#NIICDFreqGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: NIICDDS,

            columns: [
                   { field: "Id", title: "Freq ID", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                { field: "Frequency", title: "Frequency Test", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }
            ],
            toolbar: ["create"],
            editable: "inline"

        });






    });
```

And here is the web api controller:

```
     [ResponseType(typeof(FREQUENCY))] 
    public IHttpActionResult PostFREQUENCY(FREQUENCY testfreq)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.FREQUENCIES.Add(testfreq);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (FREQUENCYExists(testfreq.Id))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = testfreq.Id }, testfreq);
    }
```

The error is the last line:

```
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Request, Method=POST, Url=http://localhost:29858/api/NIICDFreq, Message='http://localhost:29858/api/NIICDFreq'
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='NIICDFreq', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='CFETSWebAPI.Controllers.Frequency.NIICDFreqController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='CFETSWebAPI.Controllers.Frequency.NIICDFreqController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected action 'PostFREQUENCY(FREQUENCY testfreq)'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Value read='DomainModelModule.FREQUENCY'', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Parameter 'testfreq' bound to the value 'DomainModelModule.FREQUENCY'', Operation=FormatterParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : Message='Model state is invalid. 
testfreq.FREQ_POOL: The FREQ_POOL field is required.,testfreq.FREQ_TYPE: The FREQ_TYPE field is required.', Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
```

And of course testfreq has all null values.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "Is there some framework that can generate local model classes from an EF database?" Breeze.js.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. I am new to web dev obviouslly. Is there a way to generate the local JS models through a web api or something? That way I could do something like "var test = GenerateBlankMyClassObjectFromServerAPI()". Or maybe it would be better to just use breeze? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you shared no code, I can only make an assumption. However, I think you're confused with the error message. Neither Kendo or Angular are responsible. They do not "initialize" classes. You said yourself, the data is there on the client.

From what it sounds like to me, the data arrives at your controller action, and the compiler does not know how to initialize your class. Make sure your Class B has a constructor defined in your server-side code. Even an empty constructor will suffice, unless the members of the class need explicit initialization themselves.

```
public class B {
  // constructor
  public B() {
    // initialize class members
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion to no avail. I get the same error. I do want to be able to pass the FREQUENCY to my controller with null nav properties and set them inside the controller.

Comment: Have you inspected the request payload during debug or in your browser's dev tools to see that the data is being passed to your server?

Comment: The payload is "{models: [{Id: 0, Frequency: "5746"}]}", so it doesnt have data for the other navigation properties. Hence why I assumed I needed to either set them as not required for the model and add them in the controller, or use breeze and initialize local models and set them.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Yes, you either need to generate empty models on the client before posting, or, change the navigation property so that it is not required. I would vote for the latter and add the dependent models to the Frequency class within your controller action manually. In short, this problem has to do with your Entity Framework model configuration.